# Is there a better way to display a long list of entries in admin.py

Tags: django, listview, user-interface, django-admin

I am building a web site backend in Django.

As the number of pages grows in my website, the list of all site pages (necessary to be able to modify a given page) is starting to become unwieldy.

Are there any techniques for **grouping or collapsing entries** in a long list in admin.py?

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of the list being too long? Are you referring to the list view where it shows you all the instances of a specific model? Or are you referring to the first page where it lists all the models types?

Comment: I'll add a screenshot tomorrow but I'm talking about a list of instances of a specific model (Page) with 4-5 columns. It would be nice to show only active pages, only pages in a specific language, or group them in folders somehow. Think Wordpress list of pages.

Comment: By default the admin paginator shows a 100 items per page. Would decreasing the number of items per page help? You can override/decrease that in your `admin.py` by setting the [list_per_page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_per_page) value.

Comment: You can also try adding some fields to [list_filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter). This will allow you to quickly filter out pages based on, for example, an `active` or a `language` field.

Comment: Other than that I'm not aware of any quick solutions to your problem. Anything more advanced will most likely require overriding the admin templates.

Comment: malberts list_filter sounds perfect. If you want to write an answer I'll select it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your grouping fields to the `list_filter` setting in your `admin.py` to enable easy filtering of your items.

Refer to the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter

Comment: Thanks again, that was a perfect solution. I was sure there would be an easy way to do it but I didn't know what to search for.